# How to have onSearchRequested not open a web browser

Tags: android

I have a button in my app.  When it is pressed I call the onSearchRequested() method.  When this is called the stock search box comes up so the user can type some junk in there.  When they press "Go" I need the results returned back to my application but instead the stock browser is opened and a google search is performed.  How can I tell it to return the results to my application instead.

I've tried these items in my manifest.xml file:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
android:value=".MainActivity" />

<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTop"

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />                         
</intent-filter>
```

I've also tried to capture the result in my onCreate with this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();        
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered fairly well in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html). In particular, you are missing the searchable `<meta-data>` element (and, presumably, the corresponding XML file). [Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Search/Lorem/) showing the use of search within an application.

Comment: I was creating my app from a sample similar to that one.  I've tested your demo out and it does work, so it's just a matter of me getting the right peices moved over i suppose.  I'll keep you updated.